# Django queryset return values that don't match

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am building a viewset that takes in zip codes and attempts to match them to my database (Postgresql). Finding the matches is no problem, but I'm curious about the best way to return the values that have no matches in the DB.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want it to give me back what it can't find in this query.

```
locations = ['77449', '11368', '60629', '99999']
valid_locations = Location.objects.filter(code__in=locations).distinct()
```

Is there a method I missed that gives me back any locations that don't match my filter - in this case `99999`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution at this point is to get a `set()` of the matches and subtract it from the original location list.

```
# Subtracting two sets to get the difference and find invalid locations
valid_locations = Location.objects.filter(code__in=locations).distinct().values_list('code', flat=True)
invalid_locations = set(locations) - set(valid_locations)
```

I can raise a custom exception and send the `invalid_locations` back as an error in the api.

Here's my output with the above code

```
In [1]: from locations.models import Location

In [2]: locations = ['77449', '11368', '60629', '99999']

In [3]: valid_locations = Location.objects.filter(code__in=locations).distinct().values_list('code', flat=True)

In [4]: set(locations) - set(valid_locations)
Out[4]: {'99999'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Django model Q objects to filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

or in your case a simple .exclude(code__in=locations) can also work